# An alternative function to the "uniroot" and "uniroot.all" function in R

Tags: r, function, package

I am trying to find the root of an equation and using this root, I am trying to find a value called "bias" by running 10000 iterations (related to Statistics).

I am using the `uniroot` function in R in order to find out the root, but the problem is that after the 10000 iterations for a number of times, the values are not converging.

I told my professor about this and he told me to find out an alternative function to `uniroot` and `uniroot.all` function in R.

Can anyone help me in finding such an alternative function in R ?

EDIT: My function is given below:

```
  f=function(p)
  {
    g=NULL
    h=0
    for(i in 1:length(a1))
    {
      h=mat1[i,2]/dpois(mat1[i,1],p)
      g[i]=((mat1[i,1]/p)-1)*(dpois(mat1[i,1],p)^(1+alpha))*(((h^A)-1)/A)
      h=0
    }
    sum(g)
  }
  msde[k]=uniroot(f,c(1,10))$root
```

I need to find an alternative function to `uniroot`, because the value of msde[k] are coming out to be significantly different during different runs. The values of `msde[k]` during different runs are not converging.

Comment: Can you add your equation and a reproducible example?

Comment: I have provided my estimating equation (represented as a function of `p` here) in my question. Here, I want an alternative to "uniroot".

Comment: What is `a1`? Please plot your function `f` first as it is not working. Perhaps that is the reason: `x <- seq(1,10,01)`, `y <- f(x)` and `plot(x,y)`